# Javascript - Why isn't my call back working? I'm getting an empty array instead of array of even numbers

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to filter the array using callbacks, where it returns only even numbers,
But im getting [] empty array as output, I defnitely wanna make use of isEvenOrOdd

```
enter code here
//Defining an array
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

//Define callback function isEvenOrOdd; Making use of this function is mandatory
function isEvenOrOdd(x){
  // let x;
  (x) => (x % 2 === 0)
  console.log(x % 2);
}

//Call callback function in main function filter
function filterNumbers(array, callback){
  return array.filter(callback);
  // console.log(callback)
}

//Displays only even numbers
filterNumbers(numbers, isEvenOrOdd);
```

Comment: `(x) => (x % 2 === 0)` does nothing and `isEvenOrOdd` doesn't return a value. I think you meant `const isEven = n => n % 2 === 0;`. This seems way over-engineered though, `numbers.filter(e => e % 2 === 0)` is the most direct way to get even numbers.

Comment: Result is not right? Or anything is not working in your code? You need to give more info about your question.

Comment: you should return boolean value out of the function, This should work - `function isEvenOrOdd(x){
 return x % 2 === 0;
}`

Comment: Please do some research it will help you understand why this does not work

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, 
I was trying to understand the complexity of callbacks in this problem and just relaized (x) => (x % 2 === 0) is returning a boolean and not a value,

was trying to mimc the syntax of filter there

Now i Understood, thanks to all your answers, those helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isEvenOrOdd(x){
   console.log(x % 2);
  return (x % 2) === 0
 
}

function filterNumbers(array, callback){
  return array.filter(callback);
}

filterNumbers(numbers, isEvenOrOdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fix your code.
You must read [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before see result code.

> A notice:
>
> - Array filter is return a array as result.
> - Array filter need a boolean return inside callback function. TRUE is keep value, and FALSE is remove value.

** Your wrong is written the console.log in wrong place, and don't understand clearly what array filter need and do.

```
//Defining an array
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

//Define callback function isEvenOrOdd; Making use of this function is mandatory
function isEvenOrOdd(x){
  // let x;
  return x % 2 === 0;
}

//Call callback function in main function filter
function filterNumbers(array, callback){
  return array.filter(callback);
  // console.log(callback)
}

//Displays only even numbers
var r = filterNumbers(numbers, isEvenOrOdd);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return true/false from the `isEvenOrOdd` function in order to get the result

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function isEvenOrOdd(x){
  return (x % 2 === 0)
}

//Call callback function in main function filter
function filterNumbers(array, callback){
  return array.filter(callback);
}

//Displays only even numbers
const result = filterNumbers(numbers, isEvenOrOdd);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let evenNumbers = [];

function isEvenOrOdd(x){
  return x % 2 == 0;
}

function filterNumbers(array, callback){
  return array.filter(callback);
}

evenNumbers = filterNumbers(numbers, isEvenOrOdd);

console.log(evenNumbers);
```